# will eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ change if switch its several rows or columns?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutations

Assume I have a matrix $A$. and $P$ is a permutation matrix.

will the eigenvalue of $A$ be equal to $PA$ or $AP$?

$PA$ and $AP$ means switch $A$'s column or rows.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ are 3 and -1. The eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1\\1 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$ are 3 and +1. This provides a counterexample. Surely this is not the question you intended?

Comment: It's fairly rude to give an order like "Show the proof", especially when you haven't shown any work or thoughts of your own.

Comment: I remove it. sorry for my bad english expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the eigenvalues can change.  Consider the identity matrix and 
$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1& 0 \end{array}\right)$.  (hint: the determinant of the latter matrix has determinant -1)

Comment: Will it be just the sign of the eigenvalues? Or can the absolute values also change? What about the eigenvectors?

Comment: Found this answer to my question above: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190388/relation-between-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-after-row-swap?rq=1