# Relation between Eigenvalues of a matrix after Row swap

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If i have a matrix like 
\begin{align*}
M=
  \begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
4&-17&8
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

and merely exchange rows $R_1$ and $R_3$, so i have

\begin{align*}
M'=
  \begin{pmatrix}
4&-17&8\\
0&1&0 \\
0&0&1 
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

we find the eigenvectors of the row-exchanged matrix are really nice, i.e. $\Lambda' = (\lambda_1',\lambda_2',\lambda_3')=(1,1,4)$,
whereas the eigenvalues of the original matrix are not nice.. My question is, is there a relation between the eigenvalues of matrix $M'$ and the eigenvalues of $M$ ?

Comment: You are replacing $M$ with $M'=PM$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix. If you also apply $P^T$ from the right and compute $M'' = PAP^T$, then you will also have permuted the columns and preserved the eigenvalues. This follows from the fact that $P^{-1} = P^T$ for a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no relation. For instance, if$$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&a&b\\0&0&c\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$then its only eigenvalue is $0$. And indeed $0$ is also an eigenvalue of $M'$, but so are $\dfrac12\left(\pm\sqrt{4 a b+c^2}+c\right)$.

Comment: are there also changes to the eigenvectors? If you know of a reference where this is studied at length showing an example with the eigenvector and eigenvalues, that would be great.